# Sum of $(\tan{12°}/\cos{24°})+(\tan{24°}/\cos{48°})+(\tan{48°}/\cos{96°})+(\tan{96°}/\cos{192°})$

Tags: trigonometry

$$(\tan{12°}/\cos{24°})+(\tan{24°}/\cos{48°})+(\tan{48°}/\cos{96°})+(\tan{96°}/\cos{192°})$$

it should equals **0 - zero**. But I don't know how?

Can anyone help me with this? Thank You!

Comment: Please do not destroy the content of a question simply to mark it closed.  Questions are not like bugs in a bug tracker.  After they are answered, they should generally be left open to be viewed by others.  Closing is only appropriate for questions that don't belong on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$${\tan(x)\over\cos(2x)}={2\sin(x)\cos(x)\over 2\cos^2(x)\cos(2x)}={\sin(2x)\over (\cos(2x)+1)\cos(2x)}=\sin(2x)({1\over \cos(2x)}-{1\over \cos(2x)+1})$$

$$=\tan(2x)-{\sin(2x)\over\cos(2x)+1}=\tan(2x)-{2\sin(x)\cos(x)\over 2\cos^2(x)}=
\tan(2x)-\tan(x)$$

Comment: Thank you very much